# How can I output a price in dollars or have it display a word if the price variable is 0?

Tags: angularjs

I have this HTML code on my web page:

```
<div>{{ row.price }}</div>
```

How can I make it so that the price is displayed in dollars or if the price is 0 then it displays the word "Free" ?

Comment: `{{row.price > 0 ? (row.price | currency) : 'Free'}}`

Comment: Is there a way that I can show that with the dollar symbol also ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To display the currency, you can use `currency` filter.
  `<div>{{row.price | currency}}</div>`
- To show "Free" for a zero dollar item, you can add another div with text "Free" and handle the visibility of both these divs conditionally based on the value of `row.price`
- Or a simpler approach could be `{{row.price==0?'Free':(row.price|currency)}}`

Comment: Can you show what you mean with another DIV for the Free? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apply the currency filter:

```
<span ng-show="row.price">{{ row.price | currency }}</span>
<span ng-hide="row.price">Free</span>
```

`0` is falsy

Comment: Since that's mutually exclusive conditions, `ngSwitch` would be far better.